# How to convert string to byte array and send it over socket in python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string and would like to send them over the socket. How to send it using python 3.6?

```
string1 = "0001ff438a9b"
```

I would like to convert the sting and send it as `bytes 0x00, 0x01,0xff,0x43,0x8a,0x9b` over the socket.

It's different from the question marked as duplicate. My actual byte values are stored as string.

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to type bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to do this, but this works:

```
string1 = "0001ff438a9b"
hexSplits = [string1[index:index + 2] for index in range(0, len(string1), 2)] # split the string every 2 characters
normalizedSplits = [int("0x" + hexSplits[index], 16) for index in range(len(hexSplits))] # transform every split to base10 int
bytes = bytes(normalizedSplits) # join normalizedSplits into bytes variable as bytes
```

Now you can send bytes variable between sockets!

Comment: Awesome! It's what exactly I wanted.